# How do I get a value from an Angular repeat loop into a button's onclick method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an Angular project where I need to get the ID of an item stored in the controller. I'm printing the data to a table using this code (Edited down to see the problem area:

```
    <div ng-app="application" ng-controller="services_controller">
        <table>
            ...
            <tr ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages | orderBy:'environment'">
                <td>{{x.id}}</td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="ping({{x.id}});" value="Ping"></td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:nodomevents] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/nodomevents
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at $get.c.push.compile.pre (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:68:382)
    at Z (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:70:149)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:59:14)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:50:415
    at $get.h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:52:283) <input type="button" onclick="ping({{x.id}});" value="Ping">
```

Obviously, the onclick section is wrong. I was wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible in a clean manner.

Comment: Why are you using `onclick` over `ngClick`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead of onClick

Try like this

```
<input type="button" ng-click="ping(x);" value="Ping">
```

**controller**

```
$scope.ping=function(x){
  console.log(x.id);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick response.